# Is the usage of 'with' right?

Tags: word-usage

> The mid and northern regions are humid and snowy with less than four months during which average temperature exceed 10℃.

This is from an English textbook for the Japanese high school students who study for the entrance exams for colleges.

I don't understand why they say 'with' in this sentence.  Is it possible to say 'for' instead?

Comment: *Is it possible to say 'for' instead?* Prepositions are very difficult to define; they act **in context** and, together with their noun/noun phrase/clause, as modifiers  "With"should be understood as "[and they (= "winters") are] accompanied by". If you use "for",  "for", in context, means "[and they have] a duration of".  You will see that with and for cause the sentence to have slightly different meanings.

Answer (score 1):

The usage of 'with' is correct, but it should be 'the average temperature' or 'average temperatures'. Also, using 'for' instead of with would change the meaning

Comment: Thank you for answering me. I understand that there would be  a difference, but I'd like to know what the difference would be like.  Could you give me more details if you don't mind. Thank you.